# Explanation of Hoel, Port, Stone Chapter 2, Example 6 on Combinatorics

Tags: probability, permutations, binomial-coefficients, combinations

It's not really an example, more like a definition. The issue I am having is understanding how the second sentence is true. For example 52 choose 25, has r < n, but the result, $i_{25}$, (a gigantic number) is definitely larger than n, not less than n. So I don't really understand what the example is supposed to be saying.

The example is:

Consider the set of number $\{1,2,...n\}$. Then if $1 \leq r \leq n$, there are exactly $ n \choose r$ choices of numbers $i_1, i_2, ..., i_r$ such that $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < ... < i_r \leq n$. Indeed, each of the $(n)_r$ choices of r *distinct* numbers from 1 to n has r! reorderings exactly one of which satisfies the requirement. Thus the number of distinct choices of numbers satisfying the requirement is the same as the number of distinct subets of size r that can be drawn from the set $\{1,2,...n\}$.

Comment: The $i_r$ are supposed to be numbers between $1$ and $n$. Looking at a smaller example, say $n = 5$, $r = 3$. Then you could have $i_1 = 1$, $i_2 = 2$, $i_3 = 3$. Or $i_1 = 1$, $i_2 = 3$, $i_3 = 5$. Or $i_1 = 2$, $i_2 = 3$, $i_3 = 4$. And so on. The second sentence is saying that there are $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ ways you can do this.

Comment: So the example is basically a restatement of how combinations work?

Comment: What is the reason for the i's having to be in ascending order? (referring to this: $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < ... < i_r \leq n$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{r}$ gives the number of possibilities to select $r$ pairwise different elements from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

> Whenever we make a specific selection of $r$ elements we can sort them in increasing order. We denote the $r$ elements $i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_r$ respecting this ordering so that
>   \begin{align*}
> 1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\leq n
> \end{align*}
>   This way we obtain a *unique* representation of each specific selection, namely as $r$-tuple $(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_r)$.

The key word is *unique*, since now we can also argue that whenever we see an inequality chain of non-negative integers 
\begin{align*}
1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\leq n
\end{align*}
it corresponds to one and only one selection of $r$ pairwise different elements from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

> We conclude for non-negative integers $n$:
>   \begin{align*}
> |\{(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_r)\in\mathbb{N}^r: 1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_r\leq n\}|=\binom{n}{r}
> \end{align*}

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @Slade: You're welcome! :-)